# How do I remove special characters in URL codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How do I remove special characters in URL codeigniter. I really confuse why this codeigniter getting the "#" or other ('Special Characters) in href and putting it in URL.

for example:

```
<a href="#" class="drop-down">Company</a>
<a href='company'> Add company </a>


URL shows:
localhost/app/home/#company
```

Any help? thanks

Comment: What happens if you remove the `#` from the `<a>` tag?

Comment: hi @ViktorSvensson dropdown will not work because it refreshes when you click without #.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `href="#"`, e.g. link like this: `<a class="drop-down">Company</a>`?

Comment: @ViktorSvensson it shows localhost/app/home#company same only

Comment: If you want to refresh the page on drop down click use jquery or JavaScript no need of #???

Answer (score 2):

> Load your helper url. Like this `$this->load->helper('url');`
>
> then use

```
url_title()
```

> Takes a string as input and creates a human-friendly URL string. This
>   is useful if, for example, you have a blog in which you'd like to use
>   the title of your entries in the URL.

```
Example:
$title = "What's wrong with CSS?";
$url_title = url_title($title);

// Produces: Whats-wrong-with-CSS
```

Answer (score 0):

**# is called hash.**

You click on 1 link, the hash adds to your url.

You click on 2 link, it tries to go to `url#company`, **browser will recognize anything after # symbol as hash.**

Try to avoid this by putting `onClick()` javascript event on button and returning false.

Answer (score 0):

The change you need to make is in the company url.

```
<a href="/app/home/company">Add company</a>
```

The # in a url identifies a fragment within a document.